# Subtle difference between copyMutableArray and copyMutableArray#

Tags: arrays, haskell, ghc

If you look at the documentation for [copyMutableArray#](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.22/base-4.11.1.0/GHC-Exts.html#v:copyMutableArray-35-), it says

> Given a source array, an offset into the source array, a destination array, an offset into the destination array, and a number of elements to copy, copy the elements from the source array to the destination array. Both arrays must fully contain the specified ranges, but this is not checked. In the case where the source and destination are the same array the source and destination regions may overlap.

This resembles the memmove syscall.
On the other hand, the wrapper function [copyMutableArray](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.22/primitive-0.6.3.0/Data-Primitive-Array.html#v:copyMutableArray) says

> Copy a slice of a mutable array to another array. The two arrays may not be the same.

This resembles memcpy, even though its definition mostly just forwards the arguments to `copyMutableArray#`

```
copyMutableArray (MutableArray dst#) (I# doff#)
                 (MutableArray src#) (I# soff#) (I# len#)
  = primitive_ (copyMutableArray# src# soff# dst# doff# len#)
```

Is there a meaningful difference between the two or is this an error in the documentation?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're even asking. Just file a bug report against `primitive`; the documentation is wrong.

Comment: It is my first time messing around with primitives, so I didn't know if I was missing some important detail (aliasing?), or whether I was correct.

Comment: Nah. The only meaningful differences are boxed vs unboxed arguments and (for reasons I really don't know) the order of the arguments.

Answer (score 2):

As dfeuer has pointed out in the comments, this is a mistake. The [pull request](https://github.com/haskell/primitive/pull/220) with the fix has been merged.

Comment: Thanks for improving `primitive`!